# Predicting binary dependent gives non-binary predictions

Tags: r, regression, logistic, logit, probit

I am trying to predict the result of an experiment (binary dependent variable) based on a number of continuous independent variables. When I do this using a largish model (9 main effects + 2 factor interaction) it seems to "work" meaning I get a plot where the predicted values are 0/1. However, if I reduce the model to say just two main effects + interaction, I get predicted values ranging from 0 - 1 (and several points in between). I have tried using probit and logit with `glm()` in R.

With the smaller model I get no warnings / errors. With the larger one I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

What causes this behaviour?

How can I determine which of the main effects and/or interaction terms are the most important (they all have `***` in the summary)?

Answer (score 3):

*These are frequently asked questions.  You should spend some time reading through related threads on CV and learning more about statistics and logistic regression.*

Linear (OLS) regression predicts $\hat \mu_{x_i}$, the mean of the distribution of $Y$ when $X=x_i$.  Logistic regression predicts $\hat\pi_{x_i}$, the probability of 'success' when $X=x_i$.  It is *supposed* to give predicted probabilities.  If it doesn't give predicted probabilities, something has gone wrong.

In your case, you have perfect [separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_%28statistics%29).  You may want to read this answer by @scortchi: [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68917/7290)

Regarding your question about how to tell which variables "are the most important", this largely cannot be done.  I discuss the issue at the bottom of my answer here: [Multiple linear regression for hypothesis testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25707/7290).

The issue of which link function to use is orthogonal to the problems you are facing.  However, if you want to get a better understanding of them, and perhaps even logistic regression in general, it may help you to read my answer here: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30909/7290).