# Bayesian updating when data is partially observed

Tags: bayesian, random-variable

Consider two distinct coins (COIN_1 and COIN_2) whose respective prior probabilities are given by:

$Pr_1(HEAD_1)=\alpha_1$

$Pr_2(HEAD_2)=\alpha_2$

Suppose that those two coins are jointly tossed $n$ times but the outcome of each joint toss is observed if and only if "HEAD_1, HEAD_2" is realized.

Is it possible to compute $Pr_1(HEAD_1 | ``HEAD_1,HEAD_2" realized\ k\ times\ in\ n\ tosses)$?

Comment: So you observe the result of an logical AND operation, i.e. 1 if you both came up heads and 0 otherwise?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Do you know anything else about $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?

Comment: @Firebug nothing assumed a priori, but restrictions could be imposed so that the problem has a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two unobserved events for tossing heads on the first and second coin, let's call the events $X$ and $Y$. What you observe is another event $Z = X \land Y$.

**If you can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent**, then by definition

$$
\Pr(Z) = \Pr(X, Y) = \Pr(X) \, \Pr(Y)
$$

In such a case, you can use a simple model using two latent variables for the probabilities $p_X$ and $p_Y$

$$\begin{align}
p_X &\sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha_X, \beta_X) \\
p_Y &\sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha_Y, \beta_Y) \\
Z   &\sim \mathsf{Bernoulli}(p_X p_Y)
\end{align}$$

If $\Pr(X)$ and $\Pr(Y)$ are very similar to each other, you wouldn't be able to differentiate between them. However, if they are distinct and you have reasonable priors, this could work. Below I provide a simple example, where informative priors on $p_X$ and $p_Y$ lead to not that bad estimates (parameters of [beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782) can be thought of as [pseudocounts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435393/could-someone-please-give-a-concrete-example-to-illustrate-the-dirichlet-distrib/435444#435444), so it is as if prior to seeing the data we observed single head and nine tails for $X$).

```r
library("rstan")
set.seed(42)

x <- rbinom(500, size=1, p=0.14)
y <- rbinom(500, size=1, p=0.57)
z <- x * y

model <- "
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    int z[N];
}
parameters {
    real p_x;
    real p_y;
}
model {
    p_x ~ beta(1, 9);
    p_y ~ beta(5, 5);
    z ~ bernoulli(p_x * p_y);
}
"

stan(model_code=model, data=list(z=z, N=length(z)))

##         mean se_mean   sd    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5% n_eff Rhat
## p_x     0.18    0.00 0.05    0.10    0.14    0.17    0.20    0.30   818    1
## p_y     0.55    0.00 0.13    0.30    0.45    0.54    0.64    0.80   899    1
## lp__ -161.56    0.03 0.97 -164.31 -161.91 -161.27 -160.87 -160.61  1148    1
```

Without the assumption of independence, there is no simple relationship between marginal and joint distributions and your data gives you degraded information, so this wouldn't be that simple.

However **if you can’t assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent**, but you can trust that the prior marginal probabilities are correct, then it’s even simpler. Notice that by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$
\Pr(X) = \Pr(X, Y) + \Pr(X, \neg Y)
$$

So if you know $\Pr(X)$ and can estimate $\widehat\Pr(X, Y) = \tfrac{\#(X, Y)}{N}$, you can calculate $\Pr(X, \neg Y)$ by subtraction. The same logic applies to calculating $ \Pr(\neg X, Y)$. Next, observe that

$$
\Pr(X, Y) + \Pr(\neg X, Y) + \Pr(X, \neg Y) + \Pr(\neg X, \neg Y) = 1
$$

so you have all the missing pieces besides $\Pr(\neg X, \neg Y)$, than again, it can be obtained by simple algebra.

Comment: Your prior needs to encode which one is more likely, it shouldn't work if you got it exchanged, should it?

Comment: @Firebug correct, it’d give opposite results if you switched priors.

Comment: @Tim I consider the question is answered, but I need to ask if you can direct me to some resource that delves in what rstan is doing to calculate the posteriors in the example you gave (assuming independence). I mean, I wonder if the posterior of  $p_x$ is within the beta family, say, $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha_x + k +t,\beta_x + n - k -t)$ for some $t=t(parameters)$ (exactly or approximated)?

Comment: @capadocia Stan uses MCMC to sample form the posterior. You this is not a classical beta-binomial model, hence there is no conjugate prior solution.